# When does sum of exponentially many exponential functions go to zero?

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

I have $K=e^{n\beta}$ positive numbers $D_1\leq D_2\leq ...\leq D_K$. I want to find the maximum value of $\beta$ for which

$e^{-nD_1}+e^{-nD_2}+...+e^{-nD_K}$

goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Also I know $\beta$ must be less than mean of $D_i$'s (i.e. $\beta<\frac{\sum_{i=1}^K D_i}{K}$) and $\beta<D_1$ is not the best I can do. Can anyone please help me?!

Comment: If the $D_i$ grow sufficiently fast then you could have arbitrarily many of them?  For instance, if $D_i=e^i$ it seems quite clear that the sum - even the infinite sum over all $i$ - would be bounded by some tiny multiple of the first term, for fixed $n$, and thus go to zero as $n$ increases...

Comment: Well, yes if $D_i$ grows, basically their summation goes to zero regardless of what $\beta$ is. The problem is that I don't know anything about $D_i$'s, except that they are positive and finite. Whether they grow to infinity or grow to zero, I don't know!